# MacOS Catalina installer fails in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, macos

I am trying to get MacOS Catalina to work with my PC. I am on Debian and I am following this guide: https://www.geekrar.com/how-to-install-macos-catalina-on-virtualbox-on-amd-systems/#Step_One_Apply_Commands_For_The_Virtual_Machine.

I have naturally adjusted the VBoxManage.exe commands to the linux equivalents. Now, MacOS boots up into the MacOS recovery menu. If I format the virtual hard drive as APFS I get a bunch of errors related to that, but even if I use MacOS extended journal, I still get an error that says "This installation seems to be damaged, please redownload." or something along these lines. I have tried about 4 different isos of Catalina but I get the same error.

The reason I want Catalina and I am not going on Sierra is because I am on an AMD CPU, I am not 100% sure if what I'm saying is correct but I've read that AMD is only supported from Catalina and on. I've already run this command, so I am not sure if this is a problem:

`VBoxManage modifyvm “VM Name” --cpu-profile “Intel Xeon X5482 3.20GHz”`

I've also tried to play around with different CPUs but since it's booting up to MacOS recovery I am not sure if this is the problem. In the installer log it says:

```
macOS Utilities[606:2380] NSSoftLinking - The SidecarUI framework's library couldn't be loaded from...
macOS Utilities[606:2380] NSSoftLinking - The Quartz framework's library couldn't be loaded from...
```

Below I have included my VBox's chat log in hopes that anyone has any idea of what steps I could try/follow next:

https://pastebin.com/Y6NP4nwp

I've tried to try different installers, I've tried to restart the VBox from scratch, I've tried APFS, MacOS extended journal, but everything to no avail. If pastebin links are not allowed please let me know how else I can post the full logs here.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't follow that instruction in the first place. Two reasons: Firstly the page says _"apply an additional command which we’ll do here"_ - my eyes admittedly aren't the best, but I don't see the command or how to apply it. Secondly it advises to open "CodeforAMD", and has a download link to Google Drive; but the file isn't available. Maybe it's the personal drive of the writer of the article, who apparently isn't there anymore. My suggestion: find a better instruction.